# Position dropdown under button in svelte

Tags: frontend, svelte

I am writing a dropdown component in svelte with tailwind css and i cannot get the dropdown menu to be under the button/anchored to it meaning it always appears under it.

I have tried using relative and other positional tailwind properties but i haven't had any succes.
I am also new to tailwind and mainly have backend experience so this is a bit hard for me if anyone can help or point me towards an example then please do so!

Comment: There are a lot of different approaches you could take with dropdowns. A super basic solution is to get the position of the parent button then position the dropdown accordingly, conditionally rendered. No need for specific tailwind functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown example in Svelte

https://svelte.dev/repl/05d770c4baa748b2b0973afec4d59051?version=3.55.1

```html
<script>    
    // Button binding
    let button;
    
    // State
    let open = false;
    let top = 0, left = 0;
    
    // React to opening
    $: if (open) {
        setDropdownPosition();
    }
    
    function setDropdownPosition() {
        const rect = button.getBoundingClientRect();
        top = rect.bottom;
        left = rect.left;
    }
</script>

<button bind:this={button} on:click={() => open = !open}>{!open ? 'Open' : 'Close'} Dropdown!</button>

{#if open}
    <ul class="dropdown" style:top={top} style:left={left}>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
{/if}

<style>
  /* List Reset */
    ul li {
        padding: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: absolute;
        display: grid;
        gap: 0.25rem;
        margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0.5rem;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```